# django built-in password_reset change connection from send_email

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-contrib, django-anymail

In my application i'm using the built-in auth views. I'm also using a postmark connection using django-anymail for some user email notifications.

```
Example: 

email_backend = get_connection('anymail.backends.postmark.EmailBackend')
   mail = EmailMessage(
   subject=subject,
   body=message,
   to=[settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL],
   connection=email_backend
   )
```

I want to change the connection i'm sending email with in PasswordResetView. Is there any way i can give a keyword argument in the PasswordResetView.as_view() the same way i'm giving `html_email_template_name='...'` or `success_url='...'`? or do i have to rewrite PasswordResetView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the `PasswordResetView`, but you will have to create a custom `PasswordResetForm` that you can then pass as a keyword argument to `PasswordResetView.as_view()`.

If you look at the source code of `PasswordResetView`, you will see that it doesn't actually send the email itself. The email sending is done as part of `PasswordResetForm.save()`, which calls `PasswordResetForm.send_mail()`

You could subclass `PasswordResetForm` and overwrite `.send_mail()` to use your custom email backend:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class PostmarkPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def send_mail(self, subject_template_name, email_template_name,
                  context, from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name=None):
        """
        Send a django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives to `to_email` using
        `anymail.backends.postmark.EmailBackend`.
        """
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)

        email_backend = get_connection('anymail.backends.postmark.EmailBackend')

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, [to_email], connection=email_backend)
        if html_email_template_name is not None:
            html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)
            email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')

        email_message.send()
```

Comment: alright. and how do i pass PostmarkPasswordResetForm to PasswordResetView after?

Comment: nevermind this question, it works, i saw that send_email was from the form, i just hoped for a miracle so that i won't rewrite anything :)

Comment: @Daniel I know this is an old question, but how do I use the def send_email on my view? I have a class based view that uses this form.